# How to traverse java maze using stacks

Tags: java

Example Maze:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

We need to take in a txt file like above and return true or false if it is solvable, using stacks.

My question is: How do I take the characters, one by one, from the file, and assign them as points in a 2D array to push into a stack? I sort of have a bit of pseudo code below...

Here is what I have...

```
   import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;


public class MazeExplorer {
    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    final int mazeHeight = 12;
    final int mazeWidth = 58;
    public static char[][] mazeLocationPoints = new char[12][58];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        File f = new File("Maze1.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        String mazeString = new Scanner( f ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        Stack<Point> points = new Stack<>();
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            mazeLocationPoints[][] = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
            points.push(mazeLocations);


        }

    }

}
```

I have no clue how to create points out of the maze locations..?

The given maze is 12 x 58, and I have converted to string, but how I do I assign a point(x, y) value to each location(char)?  I know the bottom part is wrong, it's just to show what i want to do.

ITERATING OVER DIMENSION:

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;


public class MazeExplorer {
    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    final static int mazeHeight = 12;
    final static int mazeWidth = 58;
    public static char[][] mazePoints = new char[12][58];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        File f = new File("Maze1.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        String mazeString = new Scanner( f ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

        Stack<Point> points = new Stack<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++){
                mazePoints[i][j] = 
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: so a bunch of people are just going to insult me because I couldnt figure out how to paste in my code, delete their comments, and put my question on hold???

Comment: Your code shows zero effort. You read the file in with a scanner. What does that have to do with trying to create points or traverse the maze?

Comment: @user3349062 - Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. If you want help with a specific programming problem, you need to show us that you've tried to solve it yourself first, and then you have to put together a good quality question. If a question is of low quality or shows no effort on the part of the asker, it gets voted down.

Comment: The downvotes probably have nothing to do with formatting. But at least i have no idea what you want in the first place. But i can tell you have not even tried, with this short code thing.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to create a point from each character in the string, because it is a string instead of a list of char

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code you posted doesn't have any attempted logic to it. It just defines a multi-dimensional array and a delimitered String. Don't you have some sort of pre-code algorithm or something?

Comment: @user3349062 Then your question should be *"How can I create a point from each character of a string?"*

Comment: @crush okay, I have more questions than that.  I know the algorithm would be to create points for each character of the maze/string.  The next step would be to create a stack containing those points and as I go through those points, I remove them from the stack and "explode" to check in all 4 directions if whether or not you can continue through the maze.  The code I have so far is a start to convert the file to a string, I would appreciate assistance is moving along with the algorithm I have described.

Comment: The `String` class has a `toCharArray` method, which does what you need initially.  Check the Javadoc.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWallace for being the first person to help me.  I am aware of the toCharArray method, but wouldn't I need a 2D array?

Comment: @user3349062 You need to focus your questions. Ask one question at a time. There's a lot of information missing. Since this seems like it's probably a course assignment, what are your limitations? Are you restricted to using `Scanner` to read the file? Are you allowed to use generic collections, or are you restricted to using arrays? You know how many rows you have because you've defined it ahead of time as `mazeHeight`. As you read each line, and convert it to a char array, iterate your array as well and assign the char array.

Comment: @crush the only restrictions are it has to be all in one class, and it needs to be done with stacks.  EDIT: How do i iterate over a 2D array? (we've never worked with 2d arrays before in class)

Comment: @user3349062 Could you revise your question to focus only on the creation of the points in the Stack? Then once that is solved, could you submit a second question focusing on the traversal if you are still having trouble? I think you will find more help if you were to do this.

Comment: Think of a 2D array as an array of arrays. Each element of the first array is also an array. You know the length of each dimension: `mazeHeight` and `mazeWidth`. You used `mazeHeight` as the length of the first dimension, and `mazeWidth` as the length of the second dimension. Therefore, iterate over the first dimension. You will get an array. Now iterate over that array within the same loop.

Comment: I edited my question to be specific to where I am stuck right now...I will try what you said @crush and get back...

Comment: @crush please see new edit...am i somewhat on the right track? This wont compile I know...but how do i move forward??

Comment: @user3349062 Give me a few minutes to formulate a competent answer.

Comment: Are your lines really delimited by `\A`?

Comment: I just used that to convert the file to string...

Comment: Are there newline characters at the end of each row?

Comment: I dont think I understand your question? I just did a system.out.print of my string and it prints the txt maze so i think its fine?

Comment: Yes, you need a 2D array.  So read the file a line at a time - and for each line, convert the String to a 1D char array and insert it into the 2D array.

Comment: @DavidWallace how do I do that in a loop without destroying the current char array

Comment: If you know how many lines are in your file, you can create the 2D array (which is just an array of 1D arrays), then assign each entry to the 1D array that you get from `toCharArray`.

Comment: Do i do it like this??  while(sc.hasNextLine()){
         char[] mazeLine = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
        }

Comment: Well, that gives you a 1D array, but you still have to put it into your 2D array.

Comment: what is the code for that? everything I do ends up with an error

Comment: Try `mazePoints[i] = mazeLine;` underneath the line from your previous comment.  Needs to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should be initializing your `mazePoints` array with the static ints you declared:

```
public static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
```

But you'll need to mark them static first:

```
private static final int mazeHeight = 12;
private static final int mazeWidth = 58;
```

If they aren't meant to be static, then neither should your `mazePoints` array.

Next, you should read the file line by line instead of reading the entire thing at once:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && scanner.hasNext(); row++) {
    final String mazeRow = scanner.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
    mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
}
```

You're done. You have all your points in `mazePoints` now.

***Note*** That `new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("\\A").next();` that you were using was just changing the default delimiter so that it read the entire file at once. You don't want that behavior. Use the default behavior which reads a line at a time.

You can blindly traverse the entire 2D array as follows, though, you probably need to implement some type of algorithm rather than iterating the entire 2D array.

```
for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++) {
        Point point = new Point(x, y);
        //Do whatever with your point...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what `mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray();` is doing, yes.

Comment: So to push my traversed locations into a stack(starting on 'S'), do I iterate through the 2d array or the file?

Comment: I've answered your first question about how to read your file into a 2D array. You haven't even explained the algorithm you are trying to use to traverse the maze. ***You need to submit that question as a new question, after marking this as the answer to your current question.*** A point is a 2D geometrical point, so of course, you'd iterate the 2D array, and not the file (which you just read into the 2D array). Remember, keep your questions very focused, and you will get more help. Also, try and put some effort in before asking.

Comment: I see, thank you for the help.  How do you get the index of the 2d array at a certain character? (I need to start with 'S')

Comment: @user3349062 A naive solution would be to iterate the entire 2d array, as I've shown above, until you find `'S'`. Then your index would be `y, x` at that moment.

Comment: Here is a list of the steps I've come up with for an algorithm to clear things up........1)create an empty stack of locations to explore.
2)push the start location onto the stack.
while ( stack is not empty ) {
pop a location loc from the stack.
if we have pulled loc from the stack before:
no need to explore it again, so skip loc.
if loc is the end location:
the end was reachable!
else, loc is a new reachable non-finish location, so explore it:
add all non-wall adjacent maze locations to the stack.
record the fact that we have explored loc.
}
if the stack is empty, the finish is unreachable.

Comment: Do i use an 'if' statement to find 'S'?? It is a char value assigned to a point right?

Comment: @user3349062 An if statement could work...you should really try doing some stuff on your own now. If I walk you through the entire process, you're not going to learn nearly as much as if you discover it on your own.